# Remove Local Language Label from Google Maps

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

If you see in the 
[Google Maps Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og9Cz.png) the label text is in English and some other language (Telugu). Is there way to show label text only in English and hide or remove other language label text.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set this to remove local language

```
language=uk

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&language=uk&region=EG&callback=initMap
```

then it will show only English.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course!

Set the language of the labels is very simple. You just may have to add a parameter language when you download the google maps api. Here is an example of request in english:

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&language=en&region=EG&callback=initMap"></script>
```

And this is a complete code of Egypte with labels in english:

```js
// This example displays a map with the language set to Arabic and the
// regions set to Egypt. These settings are specified in the HTML script
// element when loading the Google Maps JavaScript API.
// Setting the language shows the map in the language of your choice.
// Setting the region biases the geocoding results to that region.
// In addition, the page's html element sets the text direction to
// right-to-left.
function initMap() {
  var cairo = {lat: 30.064742, lng: 31.249509};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    scaleControl: true,
    center: cairo,
    zoom: 10
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  infowindow.setContent('<b>القاهرة</b>');

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: cairo});
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&language=en&region=EG&callback=initMap"></script>
```

*Tell me if you have some question,*

*Sphinx*

Comment: I changed my script to this maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&language=en&region=IN&callback=initMap but still I see the English and Telugu (sometimes Hindi). The problem is to not show either Hindi or Telugu, Only English.

Comment: I will be more efficient if you give me your complete code (or just the part where you initialize the map, the script the huge modifications on the map...). I can not help you more that I already do.  Do you have the same result than in my run snippet? Consult the documentation here: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-rtl

Comment: I get the same result when I run your snippet. And my code is same as what you wrote in the snippet with differences in language and region attributes. I have looked into the documentation I couldn't find anything.
Let me be more clear in your snippet is it possible for you to show the labels in English Language only?

Comment: I can not remove the translation of the labels on the countries below. There are a simply reason: Google provided this technology for all peoples. The map should be accessible for all in their country. We traduce the most possible that we can do.

Comment: Have tried the same. Still it shows the local names.